# What is a 'temporary clone token' (in GitHub)

Tags: git, github

I'm using [GitHub Classroom](https://classroom.github.com/) to manage student assignments through GitHub.  The basic workflow is that I create an assignment (including a starter repo), the students fork the repo on GitHub, clone it to their computers, then commit/push their changes back to GitHub.

I'd like to modify their repos and push my changes (technically I just want to add a file with feedback, not change their code, but that's neither here nor there).

When I try to push the changes back to GitHub I get the following error:

```
remote: Temporary clone tokens are read-only.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/2019-BIT-142/bit-142-lesson-10-StudentsName.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What is a 'temporary clone token'?  Why am I getting a 403 (forbidden) response?

I even wiped out my GitHub credentials (I'm using the Windows Credential Manager) and it's not even asking me for my username / password, so I'm assuming it's a problem with the 'clone token' itself, not my account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That feature comes from the project [`education/classroom`](https://github.com/education/classroom).

[`education/classroom` issue 2182](https://github.com/education/classroom/issues/2182) includes:

> Unfortunately, this is a known limitation of Classroom Assistant since we use a temporary token to clone the repository from GitHub (we decided to do this so that Classroom Assistant wouldn't have to be its own OAuth app).
>
> The workaround right now is to either clone the assignment again (since the tokens would be refreshed) or manually replace the URL in the repositories to remove the temporary token.
> This process and the feature request, in general, are outlined in [education/classroom-assistant#103](https://github.com/education/classroom-assistant/issues/103).

That PR states:

> The token for a repository downloaded with Classroom Assistant expires rather fast, which means I can download all repos for an assignment, but if a student makes any changes (for example if I tell them to make changes), I have to download their repo again, because the token has expired. I cannot pull their changes.

There are scripts dedicated to leave feedbacks: [`NNHSComputerScience/gitHubScripts`](https://github.com/NNHSComputerScience/gitHubScripts)

> That said, I'm not sure if this is still my preferred approach to providing feedback to students. We are currently exploring using GitHub Issues instead.
>
> I agree that committing to the repo is not the most ideal way to give feedback. I've had this idea for a long time that the feedback should come in the form of a code review on GitHub.